# How to set cursor position inside Textarea in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to programmatically set the cursor position inside a textarea?

My use-case is tagging users.

When a user enters @tar, I'm displaying suggestions, a user will click on one of them (for example @tarik) but the focus will be lost, which is expected. I need to return focus on specific position which I know how to calculate.

I'm using Textarea from `react-textarea-autosize`

I'm defining my ref in the constructor:

```
 this.textareaInput = React.createRef();
```

I'm assigning a component to ref:

```
 <Textarea
                ref={this.textareaInput}
                rows={1}
                value={comment}
                onChange={this.handleInputChanged}
                tabIndex={tabIndex || 0}
              />
```

And with this line, I should be able to manipulate with cursor position, but I'm not.

```
this.textareaInput.current._ref.focus();    
this.textareaInput.current._ref.selectionStart = 1;
```

or

```
 this.textareaInput.current._ref.focus(); 
 this.textareaInput.current._ref.selectionEnd = 3;
```

None of this examples works.

NOTE: Hardcoded values are used just to test the code.

I've tried to use `setSelectionRange` method too, no success.

Comment: What is `_ref` referring to here?

Comment: That is the only way I'm able to use to focus() method. I think a ref is additionally encapsulated due to an external component.

Answer (score 1):

```
onChangeHandler = event =>{
  if (typeof(this.input)==='object'&&this.input!==null) {
  const selectionStart = this.input.selectionStart
  if (typeof(selectionStart)==='number') {
    this.setState({
      value:event.target.value,
      selectionStart:selectionStart,
    },()=>console.log("cursor Point is in"+this.state.selectionStart))
    return
  }
  }
  }    
  onClickHandler = () =>{
    if (typeof(this.input)==='object'&&this.input!==null) {
      const selectionStart = this.input.selectionStart
      this.setState({
        selectionStart: selectionStart,
      })
    }
  }

    <textarea
      ref={el=>this.input=el}
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={(event)=>this.onChangeHandler(event)}
      onClick={()=>this.onClickHandler() }
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that custom `<Textarea>` block doesn't have a `.focus()` method.

You can try this code:

```
import TextareaAutosize from 'react-textarea-autosize'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.inputRef.focus()
    }

    inputRef = ref => (this.inputRef = ref)

    render() {
        return <TextareaAutosize inputRef={this.inputRef} />
    }
}
```

*Found on [GitHub](https://github.com/andreypopp/react-textarea-autosize/issues/183)*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

React-jsx:

```
 class TodoApp extends React.Component {

       constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state = {
            scriptString: ''
         };
       }
       handleKeyDown(event) {
          if (event.keyCode === 9) { // tab was pressed
              event.preventDefault();
              var val = this.state.scriptString,
                  start = event.target.selectionStart,
                  end = event.target.selectionEnd;

              this.setState({"scriptString": val.substring(0, start) + '\t' + val.substring(end)}, () => this.refs.input.selectionStart = this.refs.input.selectionEnd = start + 1);
          }
      }
      onScriptChange(event) {
         this.setState({scriptString: event.target.value});
      }
      render() {
          return (
              <textarea rows="30" cols="100" autofocus="true"
                        ref={this.textareaInput}
                        rows={1}
                        onFocus={ this.onFocus } 
                        onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)}
                        onChange={this.onScriptChange.bind(this)} 
                        value={this.state.scriptString}/>



          );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
      <TodoApp />,
      document.getElementById('container')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution setting both `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` on the same value.

Comment: the answer isn't detailed enough.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, solved in this way:

```
  // in the constructor
    this.focusCommentsInput = this.focusCommentsInput.bind(this);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();

  // the function to call
    focusCommentsInput(){
        this.textInput.current.focus();
    }

  // the Textarea inputRef instead of ref
    <Textarea minRows={1} maxRows={10} className="input-textarea" placeholder={"Comments"} inputRef={this.textInput} />

  // the action onClick
  <div className="comments" onClick={ this.focusCommentsInput }>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me like this:
(Using Hooks)

```
function ChatInput(props) {
    const { TextArea } = Input;
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    const [caret, setCaret] = useState({
        start: 0,
        end: 0
    });

    const changeHandler = (e) => { setValue(e.target.value); }

    // updates the cursor position onselect
    const handleSelect = (e) => {
        setCaret({ start: e.target.selectionStart, end: e.target.selectionEnd });
    }

    //calling to this function you can insert text in the cursor position
    const insertText = (text) => {
        setValue(
            value.substring(0, caret.start)
            + text +
            value.substring(caret.end, value.length)
        )
    }

    return (
        <div className="input">
            {/* this is the target textarea which is a controlled component */}
            <TextArea
                placeholder='Enter message'
                value={value}
                onChange={changeHandler}
                onSelect={(e) => handleSelect(e)}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```